# Antiforgery token error with SSL enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, antiforgerytoken

I've created default MVC 5 website application in VS 2013 and the only thing I did was enabling SSL.

Every time I'm submitting second form (first submits fine) on Firefox I get this error:

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Every time I'm submitting second form I get this error:

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Using IE gives no errors no matter what.

I've tried to generate and paste machine keys in web.config and it didn't help
I've tried to recreate project/restart IIS/try IIS 7 instead of IIS Express and still no good.
Disabling SSL works, but I need SSL in my project.

[ValidateForgeryAttribute]'s are set before every POST action which is called from submitting form with @Html.AntiForgeryToken() set.

**Update**

This is example of form that causes exception on submit, but keep in mind that so does EVERY submit with @Html.AntiForgeryToken() (and same Attribute decoration on corresponding Action).

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id="socialLoginList">
        <p>
            @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders) {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
            }
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Action code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

Comment: Does it work on plain http? What exactly does the form look like, which headers are sent? Try Fiddler to analyze the traffic.

Comment: @CodeCaster It DOES work on plain http, and I can't view headers on encrypted requests/responses (or I'm doing this wrong).

Comment: @Suitcaser may I ask, how was this resolved?